# Combo box selection as text in string

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have a Form in Access which uses a selection from a combo box list to drive the creation of a report.

The combo box selection is evaluated as an ID. I need to get it as a text. I've found other similar issues but cannot get it to work. Can anyone walk me through it?

The closest thread I found was http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/...ad.php?t=58062, but not sure what "joining to the lookup table" entails.

In the code below, txtExpr1001, txtIndustry, and txtSkill are the combo boxes.

The code:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

Dim sWhereClause As String

sWhereClause = "Expr1001 = '" & txtExpr1001.Value & "' AND MonthsCon >= " & txtMonth1.Value & " AND IndustryName = '" & txtIndustryName.Value & "' AND MonthsNonCon >= " & txtMonth2.Value & " AND Skill = '" & txtSkill.Value & "' AND MonthsSkills >= " & txtMonth3.Value & ""

Call DoCmd.OpenReport("IndustryCon + IndustryNonCon + Skills", acViewPreview, , sWhereClause)

End Sub
```

My code does not trigger an error.  The report opens but it's blank.

Comment: The report is puled up but it's blank. If I look at a query with the exact same criteria, it does have results. I'm positive the problem is that the dropdown selection is read by the report as a number. And I did deconstruct the sWhereClause into smaller pieces and play around with different reports before coming to that conclusion.

Comment: I've also managed to get one of the 3 comboboxes to be read as the actual text by using 'Combobox.text' and setting focus (combobox.setfocus) to it before, but the problem with this is that I can't set focus to all 3 at the same time.

Comment: Thank you! How would I use that in my sWhereClause?

Comment: Any suggestions for a file sharing site? Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to get the value from a combobox, you need to use `column_box.column(0).value` or which ever column you are referencing I think.

Comment: I would do a `Debug.Pring txtExpr1001.Value` with each of your `.Value`s to see what you're actually pulling.

Comment: TKEyi60, thank you! How would you incorporate column_box.column(0).value into the code above? I'm still working on creating a public version of the database.

Comment: Actually can't upload this file publically, but HansUp let me know if I can message/email this to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of a combo box (which I'm not sure which of your `.value`s are the combo box if any are) then you can just write something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()

    Dim sWhereClause As String

    'Me.Combo_BoxName.Column(0) is going to be how you call the combo box
    'I put it right at the front of the string and chose ID as a random name as well

    sWhereClause = "ID = '" Me.Combo_BoxName.Column(0) & "' AND Expr1001 = '" & txtExpr1001.Value & "' AND MonthsCon >= " & txtMonth1.Value & " AND IndustryName = '" & txtIndustryName.Value & "' AND MonthsNonCon >= " & txtMonth2.Value & " AND Skill = '" & txtSkill.Value & "' AND MonthsSkills >= " & txtMonth3.Value & ""

    Call DoCmd.OpenReport("IndustryCon + IndustryNonCon + Skills", acViewPreview, , sWhereClause)

End Sub
```